# CSS Rotate Icon Animation

Tags: html, css

How do I archive the following using CSS?

1.Rotates image A multiple times then switch to image B when the mouse positions on the image.

2.Rotates back to image A when mouse clicks or leave the image.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do what you want by using CSS `transform` and `transition` properties. It's really easy, but you'll need to use a `div` with `background-image` instead of an `img` tag:

```
div{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:url("normalImage.png");
    transition:2.5s; /* Transition duration */
}
div:hover{
    background:url("imageThatAppearsAfterHovering.png");
    -o-transform:rotate(720deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(720deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(720deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(720deg);
    transform:rotate(720deg); /* How many times it'll rotate = degrees÷360 */
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/HL9RF/)

[**JSFiddle Demo using ultra high speeds**](http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/HL9RF/1/)

Comment: You can wrap the div inside an anchor element, like `<a href="#"><div></div></a>`.